# Under mod $10^k$, period of $2^n$ and solution of $2^n=2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On one digit, $2^n$ has a period of 4: 2, 4, 8, 6. So $n=5$.

On two, the period is 20: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 
64, 28, 56, 12, 24, 
48, 96, 92, 84, 68, 
36, 72, 44, 88, 76,
52, 4. But 2 is by-passed. So there is no solution .

In a general case, for $k$ digits, how long is $2^n(mod 10^k)$’s period, and will $2$ be passed?

Comment: When $k>1,$ there is no solution $n>1$ to $2^n\equiv 2\pmod{10^k}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k$ digits the period is $4\cdot 5^{k-1}$ and $k-1$ numbers starting with $2$ are bypassed.  The easy way to see that $k-1$ numbers must be bypassed is that all the numbers in the cycle of $k$ digits must be multiples of $2^k$.  The first $k-1$ numbers are not multiples of $2^k$  The cycles includes all multiples of $2^k$ that do not end in $0$.

Comment: One would need to know the order of $2$ modulo $5^k$ to be sure of the first claim.

Answer (score 1):

$2^n = 2 + m*10^k$

$2^{n-1} = 1 + 5m*10^{k-1}$

RHS is odd unless $k=1$.

So this is only possible for $n = 1$ and $2^1 \equiv 2 \mod 10^k$ (which isn't *cycling*) or if $k =1$.

....

Furthermore $4|10^k$ for $k>1$ so $4\not \mid 10^k*m + 2$.  But $4|2^n$ for all $n > 1$.